# Sources of guild records of cabinet-makers in Scotland around 1815-1830?

Tags: scotland, 1820s, 1810s, apprenticeship-records

I'm looking for records concerning cabinet-making apprentices (particularly a Charles Frazer) around 1815-1830 in Scotland - particularly Aberdeen.

Comment: I suspect the sources for Scottish and Irish records are likely to be quite different. Since the first answer that came in is for Scotland I have reduced the scope of this question to that.  Please don't hesitate to ask a new, near identical question about Ireland.

Comment: Certainly in Scotland, each Guild (ie each town or Borough with a Guild) would have kept its own records. There is a site for Dundee's Guild records but I have no idea about Aberdeen. Further, in Dundee's case, at least, records were usually kept only for apprentices serving the full 7y apprenticeship who would then be qualified to run their own business. People who just got some training to do the work, probably wouldn't be recorded.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. My target was a master cabinetmaker. I'll pursue Aberdeen with the the limitations you describe here and elsewhere in mind.

Answer (score 1):

[The Three United Trades of Dundee](http://ninetradesofdundee.co.uk/three-united-trades/) is the website for the relevant guild in Dundee. The Wrights was apparently the one to cover joiners - other places may divide the trades differently, and the Wrights were themselves split up. I have not checked to see what the site holds. This may give at least some inspiration. Note that qualification to trade in Dundee did not mean qualification to trade anywhere else.